# Mysql query issue

Tags: php

My database table (**Name:Wall**) structure is bellow:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
id(type = int)    like(type = int)       wall_id(type =int)           
-----------------------------------------------------
1                 0                        1
2                 0                        2
-----------------------------------------------------
```

In wall.php file there are a text button name "**Like this**". So is there any way send a query to Mysql database after click on this text(**Like this**).

Actually i want to create a like system. If anyone like user wall post then he/she can click on this text (**Like this**) to like  user wall. So after every click, mysql database **like** field value should be increase by 1.

Normally I can send a query to datbase with:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO wall VALUES('', '1')");
```

Can anyone give me solution :-)

Comment: You probaply want to use AJAX/JQuery (javascript) for that

Comment: To add interactivity in your page without reloading the whole page again you need to use AJAX/JQuery Remember PHP is a server side scripting language, not a client-side language like javascript.

Comment: *UNFORTUNATELY I DON'T KNOW JAVASCRIPT/AJAX* Unfortunately, for this type of interaction, you'll either need to learn or find someone who can code what you need.

Comment: Ajax is not so necessary here, although it is the preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE wall SET like = like+1 WHERE wall_id = ". (int)$wall_id );
```

Comment: Well, but i want stay in wall.php page. If i use this then i have to go another page to send a query to database. I want to click just the text button then a sql query will go to mysql database to update my field value..

Comment: You can set action parameter on your form to not leave page. `<form action="" method="POST">` so when you save data, the user will be on the same page